# Split a string with delimiters with support for missing values C99

Tags: c, string, char, c99, strtok

I have a text file that contains lines of data with format something like this

```
int,int,int,string,string,int
```

The problem I have been having with functions like `strtok()` and `sscanf()` is that each field is not guaranteed to contain data.

A few example lines

```
12,3,4,example,withoutspace,57
3,,1,,t e s t,892
78,,,example with url,http://www.website.com/asd/asd/asd,2
```

Basically, I need to replicate String.Split() from C#, which would return an arrray of strings (including empty ones).

Comment: There is no problem for `strtok()`, can you please explain why you think there is?

Comment: @iharob strtok() treats consecutive delimiters as one delimiter.

Comment: @iharob Yea, so in example 2, strtok would think the second field is "1" rather than null.